# IE 8 "&P" is invisible, How to fix? (Does not occur in Chrome)

Tags: internet-explorer-8

In IE 8 I am using YUI to display a Table of data fetched from a server.

The Row is as Follows:

```
ID | Title | Description
```

The Data for the row is as follows:

```
N&P | Notch & Pierce | Press Tools...
```

In IE 8 The Row Renders as:

```
N   | Notch & Pierce | Press Tools...
```

But in Chrome it renders correctly.

The data is still there and entering this record using IE works fine, it is just rendering the row that the ID disappears.

I really do need a fix, potentially one that can be easily Globalised for the application as there is a lot of ID fields that have the potential to carry this data!

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` before output to HTML.

Comment: I am using MVC 2, and I output a lot of everything, is there an easy way to globally do this? Or am I just going to have to man up and do it all manually?

Comment: there is a rule for database: `garbage in, garbage out`. You can escape / encode your data before putting it into database. Also, you can replace all `&` in database. Simple SQL will do.

Comment: I am well aware of GIGO. I was using LINQ to avoid Database Security issues but I guess as a result forgot about this particular issue.

The other problem here is that YUI will most likely not understand that `&amp;` is actually mean't to be `&` if it is inside a JSON string.